# FFmpeg HLS streaming - Why the program date time of older segment changing when re-streaming after discontinuity

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8

Following is the ffmpeg command to stream the data.

```
ffmpeg -re -f avfoundation 
-framerate 30 -i 0 
-codec:v h264_videotoolbox -x264-params keyint=120:scenecut=0 
-codec:a copy -f hls 
-hls_list_size 60 
-hls_time 10 
-hls_flags delete_segments 
-hls_flags +append_list 
-hls_flags +discont_start 
-hls_flags +program_date_time 
-strftime 1 
-strftime_mkdir 1 
-hls_segment_filename 
'%Y%m%dT%H%M%S%z.ts' playlist.m3u8
```

**Following is the playlist.m3u8 content which generated for few seconds.**

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:10.000000,
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2020-11-09T22:07:53.000+0530
20201109T220753+0530.ts
#EXTINF:10.000000,
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2020-11-09T22:08:03.000+0530
20201109T220803+0530.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

When the re-stream happens(in case of restarting the streaming service), the program date time of older segments(before #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY) also get changed like below, which is unexpected.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:10.000000,
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2020-11-09T22:12:50.633+0530
20201109T220753+0530.ts
#EXTINF:10.000000,
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2020-11-09T22:13:00.633+0530
20201109T220803+0530.ts
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:10.000000,
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2020-11-09T22:13:12.000+0530
20201109T221312+0530.ts
#EXTINF:5.400000,
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2020-11-09T22:13:22.000+0530
20201109T221322+0530.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Why the program date time of older segment should change? Should we add any arguments in ffmpeg command to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question as I've just been experimenting with FFMPEG stopping and restarting a stream too. Though in my case I'm not even getting the correct date.

But for anyone that comes across this, it still seems to be an issue: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8989